# Old version of a global variable is used when printed in a string using %s

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to programming, and this is my first attempt at a standalone project in Python. I decided to challenge myself by creating a simple text adventure for a class project,and I'm encountering a small problem.

In this game, the player chooses an avatar. I store this avatar as a global variable `Toon` because it is referenced through out the game to determine the correct responses.

In the introduction, there is a paragraph that will introduce the player to the first scenario. Using what I call the "% method," which I learned through code academy, the player's chosen avatar is supposed to be mentioned in this paragraph, but it uses the initial value for `Toon` which is initialized as: "" What am I doing wrong?

I made sure that the global `Toon` Variable is being updated properly because I have the game print out the current value for `Toon` and it's correct.

Here's a truncated version of my code with the relevant snippets presented in order as they are in my code.

```
# global declaration of Toon, and preparing the introduction paragraph for text wrapping
    Toon = ""
    introduction = """ "Hello %s, this is the US Military. You have been selected in the most recent draft as a candidate to serve your country. Please report to your nearest deafting outpost for your pre-enlistment interview, ASAP." [...] "Hello %s, I am Commander Sheperd. Please have a seat." """ % (Toon, Toon)
    introduction_paragraph = textwrap.wrap(introduction, width = 70)

#player chooses their avatar

choice = raw_input("Who do you choose?")
process(choice)
global Toon
if choice == "1":
    print ""
    print "Greetings player 1!"
    print ""
    Toon = "player 1"
    sit1()
elif choice == "2":
    print ""
    print "Salutations, player 2!"
    print ""
    Toon = "player 2"
    sit1()
elif choice == "3":
    print ""
    print "How do you do, player 3!"
    print ""
    Toon = "player 3" 
    sit1()

# introduction_paragraph is then supposed to be `print`ed with the avatar name. Instead, it `print`s only `""` However, if i have it `print` the current value for `Toon`, it spits out the intended value (I.E.: player 1, player 2, player 3)
def sit1():

    for introLine in introduction_paragraph:
        print introLine
    print ""
    print """ "So, how do you see yourself serving your country?" Commander Sheperd asks"""
#First Descision
    for sit1choice in sit1Choices:
        print ""
        print sit1choice
        print ""
    choice = raw_input("What do you say?")
    process(choice)
    print choice
    print Toon




#here's the code for the process(command) function, in case you're curious. 

def process(command):
    str(command)
    command.lower()
    if command == "help":
            print "To make a decision, just enter the corresponding number next to your choice"
            print "Type 'about' if you want to know who helped to make this project!"
            input()
    elif command == "about":
        for person in credits:
            print "%s : %s" % (person, credits[person])
    elif len(command) >= 1:
        return command
    else:
        print "%s is not a valid command" % command
        input()
def input():
    command = raw_input("What do you want to do?")
    process(command)
    return command
```

Comment: where is `sit1` defined?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare the variable introduction before Toon is set. As such the introduction contains the initial value which is `""`.

```
Toon = ""
introduction = """ "Hello %s, this is the US Military. You have been selected in the most recent draft as a candidate to serve your country. Please report to your nearest deafting outpost for your pre-enlistment interview, ASAP." [...] "Hello %s, I am Commander Sheperd. Please have a seat." """ % (Toon, Toon) #Assignment happens here.
introduction_paragraph = textwrap.wrap(introduction, width = 70)
```

Simply move the last two lines down until Toon actually contains the user input. Replace each instance of `Toon = "player X"` with:

```
Toon = "player X"
introduction = """ "Hello %s, this is the US Military. You have been selected in the most recent draft as a candidate to serve your country. Please report to your nearest deafting outpost for your pre-enlistment interview, ASAP." [...] "Hello %s, I am Commander Sheperd. Please have a seat." """ % (Toon, Toon)
introduction_paragraph = textwrap.wrap(introduction, width = 70)
```

Or find some other common point in time where you can add the name to the introduction, perhaps only just before it's printed?

Comment: I moved those two lines to just after the player chooses an avatar, but just before the the `for` loop prints the paragraph, but nothing changed.

Comment: I go it! It was as simple as moving those two lined INTO the sit1() definition. Putting those lines **anywhere outside** of the sit1() definition meant that the paragraph was being printed just before `toon` was updated. It's 4am here. No wonder I made such a simple mistake

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `%` operator to format your `introduction` string, you're inserting the value of `Toon` into the string with its current value. If you change the `Toon` variable's value later, `introduction` will not change to match it. If you want to delay the  insertion of the name until later (when it is actually meaningful), you need to put off the formatting. You can still define the format string at the top.

```
# start by defining the introduction string, with formatting codes, but no values yet
introduction = "Hello %s, this is the US Military..."

# later, assign Toon
Toon = "player 1"

# when you are ready to print the introduction, do the formatting:
print introduction % Toon
```

Note that you may want to use the newer [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) style of string formatting, rather than the older style with the `%` operator.

Comment: The str.format method was mentioned, in passing, in the code academy course. It wasn't covered in the course. Because of this, I'm sticking to the older method until I get the basics down.